# CodeIgniter Building LIKE Query with n Number of Array Elements

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Consider this code chunk, where the switch statement takes a parameter from an ajax request, then turns it into a column name, and passes the column name to a CI or_like query. Note, however, that if the parameter is "address", I will want to compare to more than one parameter to the query, including street address, direction designator, street type (street, ave, blvd, etc), city, zip_code, and all the particles of an address, each having a corresponding column name in a table named "assets":

```
    $field = array();
    switch($params['field']){
        case "Owner" :
                        $field[0] = "owner_name";
                        break;
        case "Owner phone" :
                        $field[0] = "owner_phone";
                        break;
        case "Listing agent" :
                        $field[0] = "listing_agent";
                        break;
        case "Listing date" :
                        $field[0] = "list_date";
                        break;
        case "Address" :
                        $field[0] = "as_st_number";
                        $field[1] = "as_st_dir";
                        $field[2] = "as_st_name";
                        $field[3] = "as_st_desig";
                        $field[4] = "as_unit_num";
                        $field[5] = "as_city";
                        $field[6] = "as_city";
                        $field[7] = "as_state";
                        break;
    }
    $array = array( 
                    $field => $match
                   );
    $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('assets')->or_like($array)->get();
```

Performing the query results in this error:

```
Error: 200 , "
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Illegal offset type</p>
<p>Filename: models/Assets_model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 743</p>


    <p>Backtrace:</p>
```

Obviously the query statement doesn't like the `$field` in `$field => $match` to be an array, but needs it to be a single value.

I could populate each case with something like this:

```
        case "Address" :
                        $field[0] = "as_st_number";
                        $field[1] = "as_st_dir";
                        $field[2] = "as_st_name";
                        $field[3] = "as_st_desig";
                        $field[4] = "as_unit_num";
                        $field[5] = "as_city";
                        $field[6] = "as_city";
                        $field[7] = "as_state";
                        $array = array(
                                        $field[0] => $match,
                                        $field[1] => $match,
                                        $field[2] => $match,
                                        $field[3] => $match,
                                        $field[4] => $match,
                                        $field[5] => $match,
                                        $field[6] => $match,
                                        $field[7] => $match
                                      );
                        break;
```

...but that seems inelegant. If the question needs clarification, please say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  switch($params['field'])
  {
    case "Owner" :
      $this->db->like("owner_name", $match);
      break;
    case "Owner phone" :
      $this->db->like("owner_phone", $match);
      break;
    case "Listing agent" :
      $this->db->like("listing_agent", $match);
      break;
    case "Listing date" :
      $this->db->like("list_date", $match);
      break;
    case "Address" :
      // setup the first like
      $this->db->like("as_st_number", $match);
      // figure out the or_like particles
      $field_names = [
          "as_st_dir", "as_st_name", "as_st_desig",
          "as_unit_num", "as_city", "as_city", "as_state"
      ];
      foreach($field_names as $name)
      {
        $others[$name] = $match;
      }
      $this->db->or_like($others);
      break;
  }

  $query = $this->db->get('assets'); //does a select * from assets
```

Or this might be a bit more concise.

```
if($params['field'] === "Address)
{
   $this->db->like("as_st_number", $match);

   // setup the or_like array
   $field_names = ["as_st_dir", "as_st_name", "as_st_desig",
                 "as_unit_num", "as_city", "as_city", "as_state"];

   foreach($field_names as $name)
   {
      $others[$name] = $match;
   }
   $this->db->or_like($others);
}  
   else 
{
  switch($params['field'])
  {
    case "Owner" :
      $field = "owner_name";
      break;
    case "Owner phone" :
      $field = "owner_phone";
      break;
    case "Listing agent" :
      $field = "listing_agent";
      break;
    case "Listing date" :
      $field = "list_date";
      break;
  }
  $this->db->like($field, $match);
}

$query = $this->db->get('assets');
```

Comment: I'm seeing it. Another possible variation that will do what I'm looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably be best to loop through the array to build the query

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('assets');
foreach($array as $field => $search){
    $this->db->or_like($field,$search);
}
$results = $this->db->get->result();
```

Comment: I see the logic. Give me a day to think about this. Thanks for the useful input.